# Electron builder and asset files

Tags: electron, fs, electron-builder

I have an issue building for distribution an electron app, on macOS.

I have some folders that are in the root dir of my project, next to my `index.js`, which I need to be included in my packaged app.

After trying by hardcoding each and every file inside of `package.json`, which didn't help, I ended up with the following block

```
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "files/",
        "to": "files/",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "from": "assets/",
        "to": "assets/",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "from": "accounts/",
        "to": "accounts/",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

If I run the .app it appears that the files are not there. Opening the Contents/Resources, I see they are there, so, toying around I discovered that the app is looking inside the `app.asar` container, where obviously the files are not.

I found a small hack by adding a couple of `'..'` in front of all my paths, so it goes outside the `app.asar` container but I really think this is a bit idiotic to be the solution to my issue.

Plus, I plan to build this for multiple platforms and I have a feeling that if I go through with this hacky way of fixing it, I'll have to create a hack for each platform, which I'd rather not do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have files that you are using in the html (in my example assets/css etc.), or requiring in any file and have a folder structure like this, the folders would be automaticly in the asar.

Note: asar is read only package, you cant add, remove or edit files after creating this file.
[image]

the using of the css files in the assets/css folder is simple:
[image]
use the relative path from your html file and it would work on all plattforms.

**if you have files that are not related to your project, or not used in your project but should be available in the packaged app:**

you must use "extraFiles" in your package.json
extraFiles would copy the files to the app content directory on Mac OS, on Windows and Linux it will copy it to the app root directory. If you use extraResources it will copy the files to Contents/Resources on Mac and on Windows it will copy the files to resources Folder.

```
"extraFiles": [
  "files",
  "assets",
  "accounts"
]
```

note: empty folders would not be copied

in your app use something like [this module](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path) to get the root path of your app, and use your files with this path

alternative: use `process.execPath` and replace your executable name to get the correct path

based on your comment:
if you must load this files (css/js) in your app html, you can load dynamicly on the onload event with the solution i provided you above.

Comment: Haven't had a chance of trying this out, seems promising. My question is how will this also cover my usage of .js and .css files (which are inside my assets folder) from my .html files?

Comment: So the difference with extraFiles and extraResources is that `extraFiles` places them in the `Contents` dir while `extraResources` puts them in the `Contents/Resources` dir. My question remains, since it does place the src folder inside the the .asar, is there no flag to put more files in there?

Comment: I see your edit, and I must say I appreciate all the effort. Here is what I learned so far: if I want to add extra files inside the asar, I'll add them through the `"files":[]` param in package.json, HOWEVER the main reason I was having issues is that the .asar is readonly and I do some writing and unlinking of files, which means I do have to restructure some things in my app logic. I'll accept your answer because you did help me immensely, but could you for completion add the readonly issue as well as where files, extraFiles and extraResources add the related files?